# Javascript NodeList loop exiting on change?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a script which goes through a forum comment listing (using the Vanilla Forums software) and adds a "buried" class to all comments that match a given username (as pulled from the Username class). This works fine, except that the loop below appears to exit after it makes the first change, and I can't figure out why or how this is happening.

```
var userlist = [
    'Flowerpot',
];

var postsToDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.ItemComment');

    console.log(postsToDelete.length);

for (var i = 0; i < postsToDelete.length; i++)
{
    var username = postsToDelete[i].getElementsByClassName('Username')[0].innerHTML;
    if (userlist.indexOf(username) >=0)
    {
        postsToDelete[i].className += ' Buried';
        var author_info = postsToDelete[i].querySelectorAll('.AuthorLocation');
        author_info[0].innerHTML = '';
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

For example, the following console output is returned when running the script on a page:

```
25 (postsToDelete.length)
0 (first post that doesn't match..)
1 (second..)
```

And since index 2 is a post that matches the if-statement above, it applies the class to the post, then exits without an error (from what I can see) and simply goes no further.

How can I address this? I want the script to loop through all of the values in postsToDelete, not just the first one that matches!

Comment: A `NodeList` is "live" -- it automatically updates to reflect the current state of the DOM. So if you modify the DOM while you're looping through the list, the indexes will get out of sync. You need to make a copy of the `NodeList` as an array.

Comment: @Barmar - but querySelector returns a non-live NodeList ?

Comment: start eliminating lines of code. At some point you should find out which one is halting the loop. And you're switching between `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName` when fetching by class. Why is that? I'd just use `querySelectorAll`. And in both places where you only want the first match, use `querySelector`, which returns the first element found, or `null`.

Comment: You need to post an example that fully replicates the problem. You've not done that with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the for loop is entered, a new length will be evaluated which is not in sync with your counter i. Either do a copy of the initial array with postsToDelete.slice() or:

Replace this row:

```
for (var i = 0; i < postsToDelete.length; i++)
```

with

```
while(postsToDelete.length){
  var post = postsToDelete[0];
  ...
```

Comment: can the array.prototype.foreach work in this scenario ?

Comment: Will the DOM still update in the copied array? I tried your initial solution, but it flat out does not work, and iterates only once overall.

Comment: This isn't correct. The `querySelectorAll` method does not return a "live list". Your `while` solution will be an infinite loop. Also, `postsToDelete.slice()` will fail because the collection returned does not have a `.slice()` method.

Comment: Ah, sorry - i thought it was using document.getElementsByClassName which produces a live collection. Change to that and it will work.

Comment: This still causes an infinite loop, even using document.getElementsByClassName.